# No Socket Available message floods serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wireless, port-mapping

Serial Monitor get's flooded with "No Socket Available" message.  This seems to occur even before I Try to communicate with my Hue bridge through my hub port.  Does anyone see why this is occurring after my wireless connection is established?

Serial Output:

```
Firmware needs upgrade
Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ifiw_ym
connected to the networkSSID: ifiw_ym
BSSID: 0:B2:8F:6A:C4:28
signal strength (RSSI):-47
Encryption Type:4

IP Address: 192.168.1.7
192.168.1.7
MAC address: 78:C4:E:1:9F:B1
in loopin loopin loopNo Socket available
No Socket available
in loopNo Socket available
No Socket available
in loopNo Socket available
No Socket available
in loopNo Socket available
No Socket available 
...
```

code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>


//  Hue constants
const char hueHubIP[] = "192.168.1.6";
const char hueUsername[] = "my_hue_app";
const int hueHubPort = 80;

boolean activated = false;


//  Hue variables
boolean hueOn;
int hueBri;  // brightness value
long hueHue;  // hue value
String hueCmd;  // Hue command

unsigned long buffer=0;  //buffer for received data storage
unsigned long addr;

// Wireless network
char ssid[] = "**********";
char pass[] = "**********";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiClient client;

//0:B2:8F:6A:C4:28

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv != "1.1.0") {
    Serial.println("Firmware needs upgrade");
  }

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.print("connected to the network");
  printCurrentNet();
  printWifiData();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("in loop");
  // printCurrentNet();
  alterHueColors();
}

void alterHueColors() {
  if(activated){
    client.println("Hue is activated");

     // A series of four sample commands, which colour fades two lights between red and pink. Read up on the Hue API
    // documentation for more details on the exact commands to be used, but note that quote marks must be escaped.
    String command = "{\"on\": true,\"hue\": 50100,\"sat\":255,\"bri\":255,\"transitiontime\":"+String(random(15,25))+"}";
    setHue(3,command);
    command = "{\"on\": true,\"hue\": 65280,\"sat\":255,\"bri\":255,\"transitiontime\":"+String(random(15,25))+"}"; 
    setHue(4,command);
    command = "{\"hue\": 65280,\"sat\":255,\"bri\":255,\"transitiontime\":"+String(random(15,25))+"}";
    setHue(3,command);
    command = "{\"hue\": 50100,\"sat\":255,\"bri\":255,\"transitiontime\":"+String(random(15,25))+"}"; 
    setHue(4,command);

    activated = true;
  }
  else{
      activated = false;
      client.println("deactivated");

      //was activated, so send a single off command
      String command = "{\"on\": false}";
      setHue(3,command);
      setHue(4,command);
  }
}
```

It's also interesting to not that my print calls in alterHueColors()  aren't triggering.

[Full .ino file](https://github.com/EbenezerGH/hue_arduino_communication/blob/master/basic_hue_communication/basic_hue_communication.ino)

Comment: For one thing, your logic is backwards. `activated = false` to begin with. So in `alterHueColors()` the `if` condition will never be `true` and only the `else` block gets executed because it keeps `activated = false;`.

Comment: Second, can you open `192.168.1.6:80` from any other pc on the network?

Comment: @johnnyMopp Thanks for finding that, i've noticed that as well.  Fixed it locally, I will update.  After update it does go through the else.  The 192.168.1.6:80 is accessible on my browser.  However, the No Socket Available message still occurs in serial monitor.